# How to call attributes from a embedded_in relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have the models

```
class PersonInfo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name,  type: String

  embedded_in :person

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

end
```

and

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :account_id, type: String

  validates :account_id, presence: true

  embeds_one :person_info, class_name: PersonInfo

  validates :person_info, presence: true

end
```

I need to add a new attribute with a default that uses account_id from Person

I've tried adding to PersonInfo

```
field :account_id, type: String, default: -> { person.account_id }
```

but in the rails console when I run person.person_info.account_id I keep getting NoMethodError

Any idea how to walk backward through an embedded_in relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can only references a relationship outside of a default value.

You can add a method to PersonInfo

```
def person_account_id
    Person.account_id
end
```

But you can't access this method or Person.account_id from inside a default value